# check if a variable is of type mysqli object?

Tags: php, mysqli

how do i check if a variable is of a type mysqli object?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try the [`instanceof` operator](http://php.net/instanceof), the [`is_a` function](http://php.net/is_a) or the [`get_class` function](http://php.net/get_class):

```
$var instanceof MySQLi
is_a($var, 'mysqli')
is_object($var) && get_class($var) == 'mysqli'
```

Comment: weird...none of those worked...and im sure its a mysqli object cause i do a mysqli_fetch_assoc on it and it works..but when i add a if(is_a($var, 'mysqli') nothing is outputted. nor when i use the other 2..

Comment: @noname: If your doing `mysqli_fetch_assoc($var)` then `$var` is not a MySQLi object but a MySQLi result resource (see http://php.net/resource). That’s something different.

Comment: $var instanceof mysqli_result won't work, is_a() and get_class() though will, for reasons I do not understand

Answer (score 9):

Тhe decision of Gumbo works, but in this case must check if `$var` is instance of `mysqli_result`, i.e.

```
$var instanceof mysqli_result;
is_a($var, 'mysqli_result');
get_class($var) == 'mysqli_result';
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want the [instanceof](https://www.php.net/instanceof) operator.

It will work for derived classes as well, in the odd case that you extending or building your own wrappers.

Comment: Yes. Generally unless a poster specifies PHP4, it is safe to assume they are using PHP5 these days.  PHP4 has been dead now for more than two years.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/get_class

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [get_class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)